# how to match concept values in chatscript

Tags: named-entity-extraction, chatscript

If i use a ~concept, how would I know what the user typed?
this is like an entity in typical NLP frameworks.
eg

```
u: (I am from ~country )
  ^keep() ^repeat()
  you come from _0?
```

If the user types `I am from FRANCE` there seems no way to extract the value `FRANCE` for `~country` to echo back to the user or to use it later with perhaps `$country=_0`

I thought the `_0` might help with that, but no workie

This will work but doesn't use concepts just wildcards

```
u: (I was born [in near close by] _* )
  ^keep() ^repeat()
  you were born in _0?
```

ref docs
https://github.com/ChatScript/ChatScript/blob/master/WIKI/OVERVIEWS-AND-TUTORIALS/ChatScript-Tutorial.md#short-term-memory--_

Answer (score 0):

seems `_` before the `~concept` will allow capturing:

```
u: (I am from _~country )
```